# RxJava 2 - Call Completable after another Completable

Tags: java, rx-android, rx-java2

I'm a newbie in RxJava and faced an issue as follows:

I have two Completable objects to store some data. I'd like to trigger the first one and later on start the second one only after the first one has finished with success. The call to the second Completable should be blocked until the first one has finished with success. Also, if the first one has finished with error, the other one should be also skipped.

Looking through documentation and other SO questions it seems that `concatWith` or `andThen` should work for me. But in both manual test and unit test I can see that the second completable is triggered in parallel to the first one :/

**First completable**

```
public Completable doA() {
  Log.d(TAG, "class call");

  return db.countRows()
    .doOnSuccess(integer -> {
      Log.d(TAG, "found rows: "+integer);
    })
    .doOnError(Throwable::printStackTrace)
    .flatMapCompletable(this::customAction);
}

private Completable customAction(final int count) {
  Log.d(TAG, "count: "+count);
  if (count > 0) {
    Log.d(TAG, "no rows, skip");
    return Completable.complete();
  }

  final User user = ...
  return db.save(user); // return Completable
}
```

**Second Completable**

```
public Completable doB() {
  Log.d(TAG, "call to B");
  // ...
}
```

**Attempt to invoke B after A**

```
public Completable someMethod() {
    Log.d(TAG, "someMethod");
    return doA()
        .andThen(doB());
        // this also doesn't work
        //.concatWith(doB());
}
```

**The subscription**

```
someMethod()
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .doOnComplete(() -> {
      Log.d(TAG, "complete");
      // ...
    })
    .doOnError(throwable -> {
      Log.d("Main", "error "+throwable.getMessage());
      // ...
    })
    .subscribe();
```

When I run my app and check logs I can see:

```
D/Some method: some method
D/DoA: class call
D/DoB: class call   // <- why here?
D/DoA: found rows: 0
D/DoA: count: 0
```

Also the following unit test fails:

```
@Test
public void test() {
  when(doa.doA()).thenReturn(Completable.error(new Exception("test")));

  observe(); // subscription with TestObserver

  verify(dob, never()).doB(); // fails with NeverWantedButInvoked
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share how you rewrote this code such that it enables verifying that `.andThen(...)` didn't "happen" until after the first completable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you called `doB()`. Let me rewrite your flow:

```
public Completable someMethod() {
    Log.d(TAG, "someMethod");

    // doA() inlined
    LOG.d("class call");
    Completable a = ...

    // doB() inlined
    Log.d("class call");
    Completable b = ...

    return a.andThen(b);
}
```

Comment: I don't see a difference between my and your snippet that could affect order of completables. Could you please explain it a little bit more?

Comment: You think they run in parallel but in fact you log the two `class calls` sequentially before any of them actually executes.

Comment: Yes, I just also realized that after further investigation. Parts of the code (including logs) were called because they were not part of the Completable body. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: What about parallel execution of multiple Completables ?

Comment: @JemshitIskenderov in what context? Please submit a detailed question.

Comment: May i invite you to slack group of Android developers ? http://android-united.community/

Comment: I'm not very fond of such channels because they don't facilitate a bounded conversation about a particular issue. Also slack is semi-private and StackOverflow at least allows others to discover answers to similar issues they face.

Comment: @akarnokd "You think they run in parallel but in fact you log the two class calls sequentially before any of them actually executes." I'm facing a similar issue and I don't get what you mean with this. Shouldn't ```doB()``` start only after ```doA()```?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **andThen()** or **concatWith()** operator.

Returns a Completable that first runs this Completable and then the other completable.

***andThen()***

```
firstCompletable
    .andThen(secondCompletable)
```

In general, this operator is a "replacement" for a flatMap on Completable:

```
Completable       andThen(CompletableSource next)
<T> Maybe<T>      andThen(MaybeSource<T> next)
<T> Observable<T> andThen(ObservableSource<T> next)
<T> Flowable<T>   andThen(Publisher<T> next)
<T> Single<T>     andThen(SingleSource<T> next)
```

***concatWith***:

```
firstCompletable
        .concatWith(secondCompletable)
```